# Gradle install command to publish locally with version and groupId

Tags: gradle, java-8, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to get a Java/Gradle project to build a shared/non-executable library JAR and publish it to my local Maven repo (so that I can pull it into other projects I'm working on locally).

My `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven'
}

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
group = 'mygroup'
rootProject.name = 'myproject'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
        ,'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
    )

    testCompile(
        'junit:junit:4.12'
        ,'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'
    )
}

test {
    // Trick to run tests in parallel with as much concurrency as possible.
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
}

jar {
    baseName = rootProject.name
}
```

And how I'm invoking it:

```
./gradlew clean build install
```

On my file system I see a `/home/.m2/repository/myproject/unspecified/` directory (`myrpoject` is the name of my project and is correct) that contains:

- `myproject.jar`; and
- `myproject.pom`

I'm **so close**! I'm just trying to figure out to replace the `unspecified` version number with my configured value (`0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`) as well as how to change the installation directory to `/home/.m2/repository/mygroup/myproject/unspecified/` (note the `mygroup` addition!)?

Comment: Set the `version` in the script itself - not in any plugin or closure but on the first level or move it to `gradle.properties`.

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - can I assume the same for `groupId` and `artifactId` as well?

Comment: Nope. `artifactId` is `rootProject.name`.  You can keep it in gradle.properties but still need to assign. `group` works the same as `version`. Can be kept in `gradle.properties`.

Comment: Thanks again @Opal (+1 again) - OK I think I'm *close*, please see my edits above to the `build.gradle` file. I added the `version` and `group` properties and removed the `maven-publishing` plugin because I don't *believe* I need it at the moment. I re-ran `./gradlew clean build install` and now I see a `/home/.m2/repository/mygroup/myproject/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` directory with a JAR and POM inside of it -- success! **However**, when I switch back to another project that needs to use it, and I add `mavenLocal()` as a repository to that downstream project...

Comment: ...and then add `mygroup:myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` as a compileTime dependency, Gradle doesn't seem to be able to find it. Any idea where I'm going awry? Thanks again so much!

Comment: No, no. Add `rootProject.name = 'myproject'` to the script. Just as version was there.

Comment: Thanks again @Opal (+1) but see my edits above, adding `rootProject.name = 'myproject'` yields the following error: `Cannot set the value of read-only property 'name' for root project 'myproject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.` It *might* be easier if you could provide an answer that shows me exactly what you're talking about...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how your files should like:

**gradle.properties**

```
version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
group=mygroup
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'myproject'
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
        ,'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
    )

    testCompile(
        'junit:junit:4.12'
        ,'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'
    )
}

test {
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
}

jar {
    baseName = rootProject.name
}
```